# Implication of permanent injuries (specifically reducing an attribute by a die type) on Edges and weapon use?

Tags: savage-worlds-adventure-edition

FYI: I'm using the Adventure Edition of Savage Worlds (SWADE).

If a character in Savage Worlds gains an injury that permanently reduces the die type for an attribute, does that mean that all Edges that were dependent on that attribute are no longer valid? If so, what does that mean for the character? Do they get to replace the Edges with something else or do they just lose it forever?

e.g. A character has a d8 in Agility and buys the Extraction Edge during char. creation, which has a prerequisite Agility of d8+. During combat, they're incapacitated, fail the Vigor roll, and roll "Broken" on the Injury Table (Agility reduced a die type).
What happens to their Extraction Edge?

Does the same rule apply for what kind of weapon they can use? Let's say they usually use a weapon that has a min. strength of d8, but the character's strength is now a d6 - can they no longer use that weapon? Does this happen while the attribute is *temporarily* reduced, too (as in, they get a temporary injury instead of a permanent one)? 
The answer to this question might seem obvious, but the reason I ask is because the character in question has the Trademark Weapon Edge, and the weapon has a min. str. of d8. If they can no longer wield that weapon, does that Edge become useless?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your character wields a weapon below its minimum strength, then the character gets either a damage (for melee) or attack (for ranged) malus. Therefore, a Trademark Weapon you don't fulfil the requirements for any more can still be used, just less effectively.

Secondly, Trademark weapon allows you to switch the Weapon with a 1-week waiting period if the old one is lost. It is not written anywhere in the rules that a character can't voluntarily lose their trademark weapon to acquire a new one.

Concerning other edges, the closest to an official rule I can find is in the Fantasy Compendium, which presents the following among other options for stat boosting magic items: If a character uses the attribute boost of magic item to fulfil the requirements of an edge, they have to keep the item equipped until they buy themselves up to that attribute level in base attributes.

Based on that, I would rule that an Edge you no longer fulfil the requirements for remains inactive until you have spent the advances to fulfil them again (or the injury causing that malus is removed). The question of cases when the requirements can most likely never be fulfilled again (Two-Fisted, when the character lost a hand) would be up to the GM.

Comment: Great answer, clears it right up for me - thanks!